# swiftmailer plugin does not exist

Tags: drupal, composer-php, swiftmailer

I am having trouble sending emails with drupal and swiftmailer. When an email is sent it throws this error

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException</em>: The &quot;swiftmailer&quot; plugin does not exist. in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage-&gt;save()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">829</em> of <em class="placeholder">core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php</em>). <pre class="backtrace">Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager-&gt;getDefinition(&#039;swiftmailer&#039;) (Line: 16)
```

I am running drupal 8.5 and v5.4.10 of swiftmailer/swiftmailer and 1.0.0-beta-2 of drupal/swiftmailer

I originally had a error of "class swift_message not found" and when i went to update the packages via composer, I got this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out after I updated it, a previous coworker disabled it from the drupal UI, hence why it wasn't working. Enabling it from the drupal UI made it work.